Is there any benefit to using catboost_spark.Pool over a PySpark dataframe?
I'm attempting to use CatBoost with PySpark dataframes. I'm interested in using the CrossValidator for model selection. I have been able to get all the pieces working, but the CatBoost documentation recommends the use of catboost_spark.Pool as a wrapper for a PySpark dataframe.  The problem is I cannot use a catboost_spark.Pool object in place of a PySpark dataframe in a CrossValidator.
Should I use a catboost_spark.Pool object instead of a pure PySpark dataframe? What are the advantages of using catboost_spark.Pool over a PySpark dataframe?
If I should use catboost_spark.Pool and want to use CrossValidator, how would one modify CrossValidator (or even extend the CrossValidator class) to work with catboost_spark.Pool?
